# Where to find out Device Panel in Visual Studio 2012 on Windows 8?

Tags: windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

1.Install VS 2012 Ultimate on Windows 8, then start VS 2012, but can not find Device Panel from VS2012 View Menu. Only 3 options for debug for windows store app:

```
Simulator  
Local Machine  
Remote Machine
```

[Device Panel mentioned here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj215600.aspx).

2.If debugging windows store app with Simulator, run the app, then try to stop the debug app with Alt+F4, the app running in simulator won't closed, if switching to VS 2021 with Alt+Tab to stop the debugger, VS 2012 will be frozen and crash finally.

Not sure where wrong. how to fix it? where to find out Device Panel, is it same as Simulator?

Comment: I don't follow your steps.  Could you clarify?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Device Panel is not same as Simulator, it is a quick tool to change design surface to match screen resolutions, device state's etc., and that's about it.

here is the device panel

[image]

and it appears on

[image]

Comment: Thanks. Got the answer from MSDN:The device pane only appears when editing a .xaml document, are you editing a .xaml document? The menu item is under design -> device window.

Comment: yeah, only show's up when in design mode. Please accept the answer if this was helpful.

Comment: Its not showing for my xaml file. The menu design appears, but no entry for the device window.

Answer (score 20):

In the Menu Bar. Select "Design" and click on "Device Windows".

Comment: No entry with name "Device Windows"

Answer (score 0):

From the Design Tab You will Find the Device Window

Answer (score 0):

- The "DESIGN" tab only appears when a XAML Page is opened.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio Community 2017...

To see the 'Device' panel (aka Device window) I'm pretty sure you need 3 things:

1. Install module 'Universal Windows Platform Development'
2. Have a UWP project open
3. Have a max target of Windows 10 that is less than 10.0.16299.0

That is how I interpret what this page is saying:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/creating-a-ui-by-using-xaml-designer-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2017